# TextField used in iOS message app

Tags: ios, messaging, textfield

I want a text field similar to the stock messaging app in the iPhone. Text field should have the same look and should be expandable to allow multi-line editing. Could you please suggest a method to get this in my app?

Thanks.

Comment: You should look into custom table view cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a UITextField.

To get the height of the text field use [`-sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithFont%3aconstrainedToSize%3alineBreakMode%3a).

To have the look of the Apple's text field put an image behind the text field that looks like Apple's text field. See [`-resizableImageWithCapInsets:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/resizableImageWithCapInsets%3a) to get the image to stretch properly.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this :

[UIBubbleTableView](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/uibubbletableview)

---

**EDIT :**

The previous link was for the "bubble styled" tableview. If you want the view where you actually type the message, this is the one :

[HPGrowingTextView](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/hpgrowingtextview)

Answer (score 2):

***For other people who are searching for libraries but the ones mentioned here are with many bugs***

Here is a library:

### [SlackTextViewController](https://github.com/slackhq/SlackTextViewController)

A drop-in `UIViewController` subclass with a growing text input view and other useful messaging features. Meant to be a replacement for `UITableViewController` & `UICollectionViewController`.

[image]

Comment: Hey! do you have any idea of how to use this component along with RubyMotion? (fingers crossed ;-))